# Conditional Independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Consider three r.v. X,Y and Z. The r.v. X is independent of Z given Y  (i.e. $X \perp Z \ | \ Y$)

then the following is true (for some reason):

$Pr[x,y,z] = \frac{Pr[x,y]Pr[y,z]}{Pr[y]} = Pr[x,y]Pr[z|y]$

The proof of this statement would obvious if all three variables were independent of each other, since we could just cancel the "extra" Pr[y] in the numerator. But without this condition, how can you show that the above relation is true?

(I am only concerned about any of the right equalities being compared to P[x,y,z]. The last equality is obviously true given the definition of conditional probs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
P(x,y,z) &= P(x,z|y)P(y)     & \mbox{Axioms of Probability}    \\
         &= P(x|y)P(z|y)P(y) & \mbox{Conditional Independency} \\
         &= \frac{P(x,y)}{P(y)}\frac{P(z,y)}{P(y)}P(y) & \mbox{Axioms of Probability} \\
         &= \frac{P(x,y)P(z,y)}{P(y)}
\end{align*}

Comment: I think it's cuter to avoid the middle equality in the problem and go straight from $P(x|y)P(z|y)P(y)$ to $P(x,y)P(z|y)$.

Comment: Ah, yes that's much nicer.